# Cannot connect Intellij to Glassfish 4

Tags: intellij-idea, glassfish-4

I have Intellij IDEA and I cannot connect it to Glassfish 4.

When I try to Debug, the error message that I get is:

> Artifact exploded: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.

I've started Intellij using JDK 8.

I don't know what can I do to be able to debug directly from Intellij.

I have set up the Glassfish 4 Server in IDEA and put the domain URL and the credentials. Then I've set the war as exploded and set the URL to `localhost:8082`

It's working with Glassfish 3. 
Glassfish 4 is the problem. 
I have the last version, 4.1.1, of Glassfish

Comment: Could you elaborate on the steps that you took to connect Intellij to Glassfish?

Comment: I've updated the description

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to get a simple Java web application running in Glassfish 4.1.1 inside IntelliJ 15.0.4 with ultimate license running on JDK 1.8 on a Mac.

1. Install Maven `brew install maven`
2. Install Glassfish  `brew install glassfish`
3. Create a simple web application through Maven in shell

```bash
cd
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=so36290127-org -DartifactId=so36290127-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp
cd so36290127-app
mvn install
```

4. Import `so36290127-app` into IntelliJ as a Maven project. File, New, Project from Existing Sources, choose `so36290127-app/pom.xml`. Accept all the defaults
5. In Intellij, go to Run, Edit Configurations
6. Click +
7. Choose "more...", GlassFish Server, Local
8. Click Configure button
9. Enter the path to the GlassFish `libexec` directoy, `/usr/local/opt/glassfish/libexec` in my case.[image]
10. Set Server Domain to default `domain1`[image]
11. Click Deployment
12. Click +, choose Artifact
13. Choose `so36290127-app:war exploded`[image]
14. Click Ok[image]
15. Go to Run, Debug and then **Hello, World!** opens in my browser[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Kirby,

Actually is still not working.

I am using IDEA 14.1.5 on a Windows 8 64-bit
Glassfish version is 4.1.1

I put the JDK / JRE 8 in the Glassfish configuration in IDEA.
I also set IDEA_JDK to point to Java JDK 8 in System Environment variables.

Do you think that I should switch to IDEA 15 and try again?

Or there are some special configuration that have to be done on the Glassfish side?

Best regards,